# SSIS Excel Export changes Fonts 5 rows in

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, excel-2010, ssis-2008

I am in the process of creating an excel export from SSIS. I have everything working perfectly however on some of the columns it increases font size 5 rows in. So for example the text in F3 is Font size 10, as it is for F4 but then in F5 it jumps to 11?

The package creates a new file from a template with the correct formatting and then populates with the query. Has anyone had a similar problem. There are a lot on google but none that I can find regarding font size changing on different rows.

Update - One thing I have noticed is it appears to happen after a empty cell. So if F4 has no value then F5 jumps font size?

Comment: Have you checked formatting for the cells in question?

Comment: @Narti Yeah, every cell in the sheet is set to 10. there appears to be no rhyme nor reason to it.

Comment: There seem to be some issues in regard to formatting when exporting to excel using SSIS. One very dirty solution which I can think of is exporting to a flat file first and importing to the excel template from the flatfile source.